# Ansible Get a string from a file and register a variable with that output

Tags: ansible

My requirement as follows:

```
  <Resource auth="Container" logAbandoned="true" name="jdbc/InfraForms"
            type="javax.sql.DataSource" url="jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://<MY_SERVER_IP>:143;lastUpdateCount=true;useLOBs=false" 
            username="XXXXX" password="qqqTyIDd7Rd4JahLDjHJH6LvQ=="
            testOnBorrow="true" validationQuery="SELECT 1"  closeMethod="close"/>
  <Manager pathname=""/>
</Context>
```

Above is the content in one file contact.xml where i need to get value of the password `qqqTyIDd7Rd4JahLDjHJH6LvQ==`.

How can I achive that through an Ansible task?

Answer (score 4):

If you wanted to try to use module that are included you could use the slurp module and the set_fact module and with jinja2 you can extract the password using a regex like such:

```
- name: Slurp file
  slurp:
    src: /your/file
register: passwordfile

- name: Set Password
    set_fact:
      your_password: "{{ passwordfile['content'] | b64decode | regex_findall('\bpassword\b\=\"(.+)\"') }}"
```

Comment: Thanks @Darney, Really helpful that module but it has been throwing the below error.                                                                                                ERROR: Syntax Error while loading YAML script, ex.yml
Note: The error may actually appear before this position: line 20, column 94

      set_fact:
        your_password: "{{ passwordfile['content'] | b64decode | regex_findall('\bpassword\b\=\"(.+)\"') }}"

Comment: I removed '\' before = then it is not evaluating the regexp and printing the message as regexp is given                                   
                                                                                      
your_password: "{{ passwordfile['content'] | b64decode | regex_findall('\bpassword\b=\"(.+)\"') }}"

Comment: I think, The regex_findall and regex_search functions were added in 2.1.0: #14696    But i am using ansible 1.5

Comment: Ahh, I didn't realize sorry about that @Devaraju

Comment: This returns an array so it's necessary to grab the first and only item.  See my comment in https://serverfault.com/questions/952835/how-to-read-a-line-from-a-file-into-an-ansible-variable/952836#952836 for details.

Answer (score 0):

You can use https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.4/xml_module.html

There is an example with "Retrieve and display"

There is a python module that you need to install with pip but should do the trick

OR:

```
shell: cat /path/to/your_file.xml | grep -e username -e password | awk -F '"' '{print $4}' 
register: output
```

And when you want ot get the value you just call {{ output.stdout }}

Comment: But ansible1.5 is my current version

Comment: shell: cat your_file.xml | grep -e username -e password | awk -F '"' '{print $4}'
register: output

And when you want ot get the value you just call {{ output.stdout }}

Comment: Thanks ady8531; i wanted to do with ansible module but no module is supoorting the need; I made it working with shell command only